# Listview navigation behaviour in an xbap versus a standalone app

Tags: wpf, listview, keyboard, navigation, xbap

I have an wpf application which contains a listview. When the application runs as a standalone I can navigate through the list with the arrow up and the arrow down keys on the keyboard. When the application is deployed as an XBAP and runs in a browser window I can do this too but when I for example reach the top element and press the up arrow key one more time the focus jumps to the url bar in the browser.

Does anyone know if there’s an easy way to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Am I the only one who has this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to insert an invisible dummy control in the tab ordering that when it gets focus sets focus back to the listview.

That's just a guess though. And a hack, obviously.

There are definitely some quirky differences between XBAP and regular apps. I'd be curious if there is a proper solution to this.